# hide custom post types with specific meta key ON admin backend

Tags: wp-query, wp-admin, dashboard, pre-get-posts

I got a tricky problem I need to solve. So say, you have a custom post type of `event`, then this event has a scheduled event date by a custom field. And this event is recurring, like every *Saturday* since the `event date` until *February 3 2019*.

And, you want a way so that `WP_Query` will output those `event` and sort them by their `event date`.

Example:

> Event A
>
> event_date: Jan 19 2019
>
> recurring_every: Saturday
>
> recur until: Feb 3 2019

That means, when we retrieve post via WP_Query, there would be at least 3 `event`s showing up:

1. Event A Jan 19.
2. Event A Jan 26.
3. Event A Feb 3.

tricky huh? Not sure if this "cloning" and just changing that 'event date'custom field, and order them ASC is possible just by merely `WP_Query`, but let me know as that will save me alot of time.

So, moving forward, the possible solution I am currently working now is to: clone that post 3 times (for all Saturdays between Jan 19 to February 3). Then update those clone post with the respective `event date`. In this way, natively, `WP_Query` would be able to list those post. Then, for each cloned post we add 2 meta keys: `_master_post_id` and `_is_cloned`

`_master_post_id` is to allow us to delegate and redirect user to the actual event post. Like if you will display a cloned eecurring event in frontend, the `slug` you will use is the slug of the `master_post`

then, the `_is_cloned` meta key is to, hopefully, be used so that in the post listing in the admin backend, `wp-admin`, the cloned posts will not appear, so that editors can't be confused on which event is the 'master' and 'cloned'. *(Note that, I'll make it so that updating a master event will also update its cloned events)*. This way, only the master will show up.

I imagine excluding the cloned posts  in the post listing can be solved by `pre_get_posts()`, *(if post has meta key _is_cloned, then exclude)* but how can I be assured that all query in the admin backend will behave like this? i.e. exclude on ajax result of post listing of ACF plugin when selecting posts; exclude on post listing when selecting menu items in `Appearance -> Menus`?

Hope somebody can be consulted with this. or if there's a better approach?

Regards,

Comment: You should use a non-hierarchical taxonomy instead of post meta to store your `_is_cloned` meta key/tag, if you need to tag a post as something, you should use a taxonomy. Filtering out via post meta is obscenely expensive, has a super heavy load on the DB, and is very slow. Querying to a tag named `_is_cloned` or even better, `_is_not_cloned` is 1000x faster and makes for an easier to write query. Never exclude, always query for what you actually want ( aka posts that aren't cloned ), and use taxonomies to store things you need to search for later